# How to configure term set so contributors can add new terms to the set?

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, term-store, term-set

Our client has SharePoint Online (Enterprise plan) and wants to use a term set for their list of client names. We want the consultants group witin the company to be able to add new terms to that term set themselves.

I have created the term set via the admin center and put the right groups into the administrator and contributor sections. However, when testing: I click on the tags icon next to the term set field and the normal window pops up where you can select an existing term from the set. However, I do not see an option to add or create a new term? Why not? There is only the little "send feedback" link at the top. What am I missing here or doing wrong? How/where can contributors add a new term to the set?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A colleague of mine pointed out that the term set needs to be created at the site-collection level in instead of central admin level (which is what I had done) if you want people be able to add terms to the term set. In summary, you need to think about the following:

1) create the term set at the site-collection level

2) set it to "open"

3) add the people/group(s) you want to be able to add terms to the Contributor section.

4) make sure those same people/group(s) have contribute permissions (or higher) on the site where they will be using the term set.

Comment: You don't need to have it as site-collection level term set. What you need to do is to allow the addition on the column level as well, in addition to making the term set open.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to specify a term set as **open** to users to be able to add new terms, see https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-managed-metadata-a180fa28-6405-4679-9ec3-81d2028c4efc

> In addition, you can configure a term set as closed or open. In a closed term set, users can't add new terms unless they have appropriate permissions. In an open term set, users can add new terms in a column that is mapped to the term set.

Users also need 'Contribute' site-level permission to add terms